# Data validation list from values in a comma separated cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to build a data validation list from a cell with comma separated values.

Take a look at the image, if a user selects "FFP-IS" the list should be:

```
ACC
ADM 
AOS
ABU
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: Sorry, Scott, I've tried using formulas, but no luck. Just looking for help.

Comment: @Gooney:  Using formulas could be very very difficult.  Using VBA will be the best (easiest) thing to help you here.  Try your best to write a VBA solution. Then come back with the code you've tried if you are still having problems.

Comment: It will be much better to have those values in separate cells.  You can get them in separate cells with a Text-to-Columns function.  And then create a named range for each list.  Given your example, you would created a named range of `FFP-IS`which would include the 4 cells which should be the drop down list (ACC / ADM / AOS / ABU).  Then create a second named range of `FFP` which would include the 3 cells which should be the drop down list (ACC / ACA / ADM).  Now you can use the Indirect function to get the dependent drop down lists.

Comment: See this link for a more in depth explanation: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 0):

You can hack the data validation list to use a comma separated list using a hidden range, a UDF and multiple Named Ranges.

First The UDF (note I have used column A as a repository for the values - which can be hidden):

```
Public Function DVList(Cell As Range) As Range
    Dim i As Long, arr() As String: arr = Split(Cell.Value, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Range("A1").Offset(i) = arr(i)
    Next i
    Set DVList = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(UBound(arr)))
End Function
```

Then set up a Named Range such as 'DVList1' with the formula "=DVList(Sheet1!$I$4)" where Sheet1!$I$4 contains your string of comma delimited values

Finally add a data validation list cell with "=DVList1"

The list will now be populated with your values

This is quite limited in scope; so you would need a different named range for each cell with a comma delimited value set; but you may be able to edit to your needs.